# ultrasonic sensor didn't work with raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I have a problem with raspberry pi 3b and ultrasonic sensor

I want to sense and indicate the obstacle

I connect it as many tutorial on google and measure it a while ago and it was working before

today i came and execute same code with same connection, it didn't need to measure
the problem is that the echo pin didn't become `1`

this is the code i used , I made a print statement to debug, but only `testttt` was printed.

```
enter code here

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO_TRIGGER = 12
GPIO_ECHO = 16
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.IN)
def distance():
    while True:

           GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, 0)
           time.sleep(2)
           GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, 1)
           time.sleep(0.00001)
           GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, 0)
           while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 0:
               StartTime = time.time()
               print"testttt"

           While GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 1:
                StopTime = time.time()
                print"test"
           TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime
           distance = TimeElapsed * 17150
           dis=round(distance,2)
           print"distabce=" +str(dis)+"cm"


  distance()
```

Comment: please review the wording of your question and add some punctuation. It's not very readable in it's current state

Comment: It looks like nothing is actually indented inside the bodies of your while loops here. Did you copy the indentation correctly onto StackOverflow?

Comment: There is a way to reset GPIOs' state, because some of them remain in the previous state, what can affect your code. Also, there is a possibility of a GPIO may be damaged.